# Show Site Name on WP login screen

Tags: customization, login, bloginfo

I'm trying to create a generic, re-usable function that shows the site name on the login screen. It works with just static text, but how do I pull in the site name dynamically? Here's what I've tried:

```
function custom_login_message() {
    $message = '<p class="natz-login">Log in to <?php echo get_option( 'name' ); ?> </p><br />';
    return $message;
    }
    add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

This is obviously wrong, but what do is use instead of `<?php echo get_option( 'name' ); ?>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`get_bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/).

```
function wpse407167_custom_login_message( $message ) {

    $message = '<p class="natz-login">Log in to ' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</p><br>';
    return $message;
    
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse407167_custom_login_message', 99 );
```

Comment: Sadly not. This is giving me a critical error if added to my functions file.

Comment: @ChanningKrendler Sorry, my bad. There was a syntax error on my code. Fixed it. Try now and let me know.

Comment: Flipping brilliant. That's exactly it!! Thanks, @Abhik.

Answer (score -1):

if you mean, the php to replace  `<?php echo get_option( 'name' ); ?>`
then it's probably  `<?=  bloginfo('name') ?>`

Comment: You mean <?php  bloginfo('name') ?> I guess?
No. Unfortunately, that's also coming with a site-wide critical error.